# Joomla 404 error only on article content with SEF link

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla, http-status-code-404, article

I have installed a website made with joomla on a new linux CentOS6 server.
I have installed and configured Apache
Installed and Configure PHP
Installed and configured MySQL
Installed PhpMyAdmin
Installed and Configured FTP
Set the firewall rules

Everything is working right, except the single article pages:

1. The web site is accessible from outside The user is under the group
2. www-data and has read-write permission on all the folders I can
3. upload media to the website and this has the right privileges once uploaded
4. FTP is working perfectly
5. httpd.conf has the permission to AllowOverride All to the directory where the site is (/var/www/sites/clientname/sitename.it )
6. When I start httpd, I get no error or warning.

if I try to access to the following URL I get 404:
http://ldgsocial.brainsen.com/index.php/test
that it's a page configured as "single article", pointing to a published article.
The article is not even accessible typing the real URL:
http://ldgsocial.brainsen.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=110

1. The record with id=110 is present in the database, and visible in the list of articles in Joomla Admin.
2. All the folders of joomla are readable and writable.
3. SEF is activated, I've tried to deactivate but both above URL return always 404
4. mod_rewrite is loaded
5. the htaccess.txt is renamed after the FTP upload to .htaccess

in the .htaccess I have the following directives:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /var/www/sites/clientname/sitename.it
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

I've tried also putting:
RewriteBase /var/www/sites/clientname/sitename.it/public_html
and
RewriteBase /
 but nothing to do.

The articles are accessible only if I create a new menu voice with type Category List.
From there all the articles are accessible and correctly displayed.

I'm pretty desperate as I don't know what to do next...

here is the installation details:

```
database Version     5.1.69
Collation database   utf8_general_ci
PHP Version  5.3.3
Web Server   Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
Joomla! Version  Joomla! 2.5.14 Stable [ Ember ] 01-August-2013 14:00 GMT
Joomla! Platform Version     Joomla Platform 11.4.0 Stable [ Brian Kernighan ] 03-Jan-2012 00:00 GMT
```

Comment: is the article published, not trashed? What are the publish_up andpublish_down values? What is its access level?

Comment: Initially it was published (green). Then I've tried to suspend and re-publish, but it says: Published but Pending (yellow icon).
Access level is public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jdog, thanks, you have given me the input!

The problem was on the **server system date**, that was wrong and set to the past.
So the articles was published, because was set on a different server, but on the new server, they were not shown as they publishing date was future to the system date..